# Active class for react-scroll, isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Active class not being shown, nor rendered in DOM when I run my page and scroll to the `<Element></Element>`

I read somewhere that you had to call `scrollSpy.update()` that was posted a few years ago. However, still not working.

I'm following the [Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) implementation

Here is my code...

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import styles from "./navbar.module.css";
import { Link, Element } from "react-scroll";
import * as Scroll from "react-scroll";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1
  }
}));

export default function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  let scrollSpy = Scroll.scrollSpy;
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollSpy.update();
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar style={{ backgroundColor: "#343567" }} position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Welcome
          </Typography>
          <Link
            activeClass="active"
            to="test1"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-70}
            duration={800}
          >
            Test 1
          </Link>
          <Link
            activeClass="active"
            to="test2"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-70}
            duration={800}
          >
            Test 2
          </Link>
          <Link
            activeClass="active"
            to="test3"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-70}
            duration={800}
          >
            Test 3
          </Link>
          <Link
            activeClass="active"
            to="test4"
            spy={true}
            smooth={true}
            offset={-70}
            duration={800}
          >
            Test 4
          </Link>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the element that it is scrolling to for ease-of-access.

```
<Element name="test1" className="element">
  test 1
</Element>

<Element name="test2" className="element">
  test 2
</Element>

<Element name="test3" className="element">
  test 1
</Element>

<Element name="test4" className="element">
  test 2
</Element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, You forget this.

```
import { Link, Element } from "react-scroll";
```

Hope is help.

Comment: Still, wouldn't work as the elements that I'm using are on a separate component. I did add the Element to the import statement for ease-of-use

Comment: Show me,If have code error, And show result is you are expected.

Comment: There's no code error. As explained, if you were to plug this into a React component. Then, inspect the page. Upon scrolling, the 'active' class, doesn't render to the Navbar element. Showing that it is active.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the Element to 'id' instead of 'name'

For example:

```
<Element id="test1" className="element">
  test 1
</Element>

<Element id="test2" className="element">
  test 2
</Element>

<Element id="test3" className="element">
  test 1
</Element>

<Element id="test4" className="element">
  test 2
</Element>
```